# Strange PolyBatch Positioning in libGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

Excuse the basic question, just getting into the guts of LibGDX

I'm creating a radial bar to show my countdown timer

I've found some code that does what I need it to, the problem is the radial sprite's positioning. I can't seem to get it to center in the Image object (Since it seems to be ignoring the Image's local coordinates and is defaulting to the stage's) so 0,0 places it close to the bottom left of my screen.

I've tried using a localtoStage and vice versa to calculate the correct positions, but that doesn't seem to give me the right values either.

Please advise

```
    package com.goplayplay.klpoker.CSS.Classes;

        import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.*;
        import com.badlogic.gdx.math.EarClippingTriangulator;
        import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Intersector;
        import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
        import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Image;
        import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.ShortArray;

    public class ProgressCircle extends Image {

        TextureRegion texture;
        PolygonSpriteBatch polyBatch;
        Vector2 center;
        Vector2 centerTop;
        Vector2 leftTop;
        Vector2 leftBottom;
        Vector2 rightBottom;
        Vector2 rightTop;
        Vector2 progressPoint;
        float[] fv;
        IntersectAt intersectAt;

    public ProgressCircle(TextureRegion region, PolygonSpriteBatch polyBatch) {
        super(region);

        this.texture = region;
        this.polyBatch = polyBatch;

        center = new Vector2(this.getWidth() / 2, this.getHeight() / 2);
        centerTop = new Vector2(this.getWidth() / 2, this.getHeight());
        leftTop = new Vector2(0, this.getHeight());
        leftBottom = new Vector2(0, 0);
        rightBottom = new Vector2(this.getWidth(), 0);
        rightTop = new Vector2(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
        progressPoint = new Vector2(this.getWidth() / 2, this.getHeight() / 2);

        setPercentage(0);
    }

    private Vector2 IntersectPoint(Vector2 line) {
        Vector2 v = new Vector2();
        boolean isIntersect;

        //check top
        isIntersect = Intersector.intersectSegments(leftTop, rightTop, center, line, v);

        //check bottom
        if (isIntersect) {
            intersectAt = IntersectAt.TOP;
            return v;
        } else isIntersect = Intersector.intersectSegments(leftBottom, rightBottom, center, line, v);

        //check left
        if (isIntersect) {
            intersectAt = IntersectAt.BOTTOM;
            return v;
        } else isIntersect = Intersector.intersectSegments(leftTop, leftBottom, center, line, v);

        //check bottom
        if (isIntersect) {
            intersectAt = IntersectAt.LEFT;
            return v;
        } else isIntersect = Intersector.intersectSegments(rightTop, rightBottom, center, line, v);

        if (isIntersect) {
            intersectAt = IntersectAt.RIGHT;
            return v;
        } else {
            intersectAt = IntersectAt.NONE;
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void setPercentage(float percent) {
        //100 % = 360 degree
        //==> percent % => (percent * 360 / 100) degree

        float angle = convertToRadians(90); //percent = 0 => angle = -90
        angle -= convertToRadians(percent * 360 / 100);

        float len = this.getWidth() > this.getHeight() ? this.getWidth() : this.getHeight();
        float dy = (float) (Math.sin(angle) * len);
        float dx = (float) (Math.cos(angle) * len);
        Vector2 line = new Vector2(center.x + dx, center.y + dy);

        Vector2 v = IntersectPoint(line);

        if (intersectAt == IntersectAt.TOP) {
            if (v.x >= this.getWidth() / 2) 
            {
                fv = new float[]{
                        center.x,
                        center.y,
                        centerTop.x,
                        centerTop.y,
                        leftTop.x,
                        leftTop.y,
                        leftBottom.x,
                        leftBottom.y,
                        rightBottom.x,
                        rightBottom.y,
                        rightTop.x,
                        rightTop.y,
                        v.x,
                        v.y
                };
            } else {
                fv = new float[]{ 
                        center.x,
                        center.y,
                        centerTop.x,
                        centerTop.y,
                        v.x,
                        v.y
                };

            }
        } else if (intersectAt == IntersectAt.BOTTOM) {
            fv = new float[]{
                    center.x,
                    center.y,
                    centerTop.x,
                    centerTop.y,
                    leftTop.x,
                    leftTop.y,
                    leftBottom.x,
                    leftBottom.y,
                    v.x,
                    v.y
            };

        } else if (intersectAt == IntersectAt.LEFT) {
            fv = new float[]{
                    center.x,
                    center.y,
                    centerTop.x,
                    centerTop.y,
                    leftTop.x,
                    leftTop.y,
                    v.x,
                    v.y
            };

        } else if (intersectAt == IntersectAt.RIGHT) {
            fv = new float[]{
                    center.x,
                    center.y,
                    centerTop.x,
                    centerTop.y,
                    leftTop.x,
                    leftTop.y,
                    leftBottom.x,
                    leftBottom.y,
                    rightBottom.x,
                    rightBottom.y,
                    v.x,
                    v.y
            };

        } else // if (intersectAt == IntersectAt.NONE)
        {
            fv = null;
        }


    }

    //
    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
        //      super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);

        if (fv == null) return;

        batch.end();
        drawMe();
        batch.begin();



    }

    public void drawMe() {

        Vector2 acc = new Vector2();
        acc.set(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);
        localToStageCoordinates(acc);
        EarClippingTriangulator e = new EarClippingTriangulator();
        ShortArray sv = e.computeTriangles(fv);

        PolygonRegion polyReg = new PolygonRegion(texture, fv, sv.toArray());

        PolygonSprite poly = new PolygonSprite(polyReg);

        poly.setOrigin(this.getOriginX(), this.getOriginY());
        poly.setPosition(this.getX(), this.getY());
        //        poly.setPosition(acc.x, acc.y); //Attempting to calculate correct positioning - Doesnt work
        poly.setRotation(this.getRotation());
        poly.setColor(this.getColor());

        polyBatch.begin();
        poly.draw(polyBatch);
        polyBatch.end();


    }

    float convertToDegrees(float angleInRadians) {
        float angleInDegrees = angleInRadians * 57.2957795f;
        return angleInDegrees;
    }


        //-----------------------------------------------------------------

    float convertToRadians(float angleInDegrees) {
        float angleInRadians = angleInDegrees * 0.0174532925f;
        return angleInRadians;
    }

    public enum IntersectAt {
        NONE, TOP, BOTTOM, LEFT, RIGHT
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to set the camera's projection matrix on the polygon batch. You can get a copy of it from the Batch that's passed in:

```
public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
    //      super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);

    if (fv == null) return;

    batch.end();
    drawMe(batch.getProjectionMatrix());
    batch.begin();
}

public void drawMe(Matrix4 projection) {
    polyBatch.setProjectionMatrix(projection);
    //...
}
```

Or more simply, you can use a PolygonBatch as your Stage's batch, so you don't have to be swapping batches:

```
stage = new Stage(myViewport, new PolygonBatch());

//...

public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
    //      super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);

    if (fv == null) return;
    //don't need to call begin and end on the batch
    drawMe((PolygonBatch)batch); 
}

public void drawMe(PolygonBatch polyBatch) {
    //...
    //don't need to call begin or end on the batch
}
```

By the way, your `drawMe` method instantiates quite a few objects, some large. You should avoid this if you have more than a few actors that do this, or you'll get stutters from the GC. Try to instantiate objects only once in the constructor and reuse them.